# Create my own HttpErrorResponses

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, http-error

I have just read this article on dealing with error messages in web api,  [Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2012/06/28/error-handling-in-asp-net-webapi.aspx)

But now I want to make a list of all my predefined errors,

I have tried this so far:

```
 public class ConnectionTimeoutError : HttpError
{
    public ConnectionTimeoutError()
    {
        HttpError myCustomError = new HttpError("Timeout while trying connect to the device") { { "CustomErrorCode", 33 } };
    }
}
```

And then I tried to use it like this:

```
 HttpResponseMessage msg = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new ConnectionTimeoutError());
                return msg;
```

Its not 100%

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use defined HttpStatus code for each request depending of situation that might happen here and handle it on client/device. Bu for some special or individual errors i would return json whic can be derived from your custom error class with some aditional informations that you cover up.

Comment: Thing is then how do I control my erros strictly, if its jsut a number i send here and receive there, I need a away to globally manage the error codes. Such as predefining them in a class, then I can give the error number and say a message that goes with it, if I just use the predefined ones, I will have to type out the error number and message every time which isnt good design.